# Ajax response xml is null Java script

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Servlet response:

```
for (int i = 0; i < projNames.size(); i++) {   
    sb.append("<project>");
    sb.append("<projectName>" + projNames.get(i) + "</projectName>");   
    sb.append("</project>");
    res.setContentType("text/xml");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    System.out.println(" test="+test);
    res.getWriter().write(sb.toString());
}
```

System.out.println shows "sb" value as

```
<project><projectName>sample</projectName></project><project><projectName>sample 2</projectName></project>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the response XML and but when I checked the length "object value is null" ( debugged in IE 8 )

```
function displayValues()
{
    var response;
    if (req.responseXML != null)
        alert("res xml is ther=="+ response); //displays UNDEFINED
    else
        alert("no res xml");

    response = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("project")[0];
    alert("child node"+response.childNodes.length); // alert is not displayed
}
```

Please enlighten. Thanks

AJAX code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
var response;
var firstName;
var icdatevalue;
function getProject()
{ 
var url ="DBActionServlet?action=getProject"; 
            initRequest(url);
            req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
            req.open("POST", url, true); 
            req.send(null);
                }
function initRequest(url) 
         {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
            {
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } 
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
            {
                isIE = true;
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

         }

        function processRequest() 
         {
            if (req.readyState == 4) 
            {
                if (req.status == 200) 
            {

                    alert("status="+req.status);//status is shown as 200
                    displayValues(); //this function code mentioned above
                }
            }
         }

    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: How is `req` defined? Please post *all* of your AJAX code.

Comment: What's the `status` property of `req`? Is it 200?

Comment: Hi, Many thanks Blender and carlosfigueria for the response, Please find the AJAX code, i'm getting the req.status =200. I tried debugging with IE develop tool and it shows 'null' for the variable 'response'  (var response= response = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("project")[0]; )